# FInd a document several times

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of events in a city, and I display for the city all incoming events, sorted by the start date of the event.

Today I need to add a new feature : some events can be repeated over time, for exemple a flea all wednesday and friday during 2 month. In this case, I'll need to display this event X times.

E.g. what should be displayed on the timeline :

```
The flea - today 2015-04-08 - id = 42
Justin Bieber concert - today 2015-04-08 - id = 43
An other concert - thursday 2015-04-09 - id = 44
The flea - friday 2015-04-10 - id = 42
```

The problem I have is that today, each document in Elasticsearch has the same `_id` than the one in MySQL.

I know i could stop using `_id` and add a `idEvent` field in the mapping, but this whould change a lot of things in the programm. Is there an elegant way to handle this problem ?

Edit :
Here is a sample of my mapping :

```
"event": {
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "dateStart": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        },
        "dateEnd": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
    }
}
```

And I wonder if with something like that I would be able to display several times the event in results, according to its `dateStart` :

```
"event": {
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "dates": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "dateStart": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                },
                "dateEnd": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards,

Comment: How are you saving the fields in the first case...I mean what is your mapping config that you use to store the events?

Comment: How do you know that an event is an recurring event?As per this mapping elasticsearch just has a single event. But, you are expecting it to display multiple times with a change in date (The date change whether it is weekly or monthly is also not available in the mapping). I don't see a way, at least from ES end to fulfill your requirement. I think you should be doing it from the front end side.

Comment: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Ranged-and-recurring-events-td1897915.html I suppose the mapping should be similar to the mapping mentioned in this url. The issue also discusses similar problem.

Comment: Thx for your link, so I understand that I won't be able to get X times the same document as result since it has the same _id. So I need to add a `idEvent` property. I wanted to avoid that :( Thx !